# How to store a checkk box value which is not checked in php?

Tags: php, post

I am new in PHP, I have Two check Boxes. User can b checked on its preference.

```
   <div style="margin-top:10px; width:auto">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="p_release" checked> Encl: 1) Press Release<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="r_report"> 2) Rating Report<br>
     </div>
```

On action page i get the values of both check boxes

```
$chk = $_POST['chk'];
$chk1 = $_POST['chk1'];
if (empty($chk1)) {
    $chk1 = "";
}
```

Here i face problem. If user is not check the second checkbox it show error

`Notice: Undefined index: chk1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\letter\letter_copy_action.php on line 63`

How i can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if they aren't empty first before you assign a value to a variable:

```
if(!empty($_POST['chk'])){
    $chk = $_POST['chk'];
}
else{
    $chk = ""
}

if(!empty($_POST['chk1'])){
    $chk1 = $_POST['chk1'];
}
else{
    $chk1 = ""
}
```

Comment: `empty()` does the same as `isset` but also checks if they are empty

Comment: No need to use `isset` as `!empty` will do the work over here

Answer (score 0):

Modify your PHP code to this:

```
if (isset($_POST['chk1'])) 
    $chk1 = $_POST['chk1'];

else
    $chk1 = "";

if (isset($_POST['chk'])) 
    $chk = $_POST['chk'];

else
    $chk = "";
```